# PHP send variable value external webpage

Tags: php, html

I'm currently trying to send the two variable values, `$incorrect` and `$correct` from a form.

I have tried to use `$_POST[]` to create this functionality, yet it doesn't work!

Could anyone help me when creating such a functionality  ?

`page1.php`

```
<form action="testresult.php" method="POST">
    <label for="qn1">Question 1: <?php echo $array_question[$question_num_array[0]] ?></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="question1_answer" name="question1_answer" required><br><br>
    
    <label for="qn2">Question 2: <?php echo $array_question[$question_num_array[1]] ?></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="question2_answer" name="question2_answer" required><br><br>

    <label for="qn3">Question 3: <?php echo $array_question[$question_num_array[2]] ?></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="question3_answer" name="question3_answer" required><br><br>

    <input type="hidden" name="correct" id="correct" value="<?php $correct ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="incorrect" id="incorrect" value="<?php $incorrect ?>" />
    
    <input type="submit" name="submitAnswers" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
        if(isset($_POST["submitAnswers"])){
            $correct = 0;
            $incorrect = 0;
            $qn1_ans = $_POST['question1_answer'];
            $qn2_ans = $_POST['question2_answer'];
            $qn3_ans = $_POST['question3_answer'];

            if ($qn1_ans == $array_answer[$question_num_array[0]]){ $correct ++; }
            else { $incorrect ++; }

            if ($qn2_ans == $array_answer[$question_num_array[1]]){ $correct ++; }
            else { $incorrect ++; }

            if ($qn3_ans == $array_answer[$question_num_array[2]]){ $correct ++; }
            else { $incorrect ++; }

        }
    ?>
```

And on the receiving end
`page2.php`

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $correct = $_POST['correct'];
        $incorrect = $_POST['incorrect'];

        echo $correct."test ".$incorrect;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with that code? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: My variables aren't displaying on the other page. So i'm unsure where did it go wrong.

Comment: Please try using javascript to set the hidden field values here.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not inspect what the form contains before submitting it (through the markup), or after submitting it (by either inspecting the request in your browser's network console, or by dumping `$_POST`)

Comment: Also, are you sure you are setting the field's values **before** posting anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your first page should JUST show the questions, it will be like this.

```
<form action="testresult.php" method="POST">
    <label for="qn1">Question 1: <?php echo $array_question[$question_num_array[0]] ?></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="question1_answer" name="question1_answer" required><br><br>
    
    <label for="qn2">Question 2: <?php echo $array_question[$question_num_array[1]] ?></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="question2_answer" name="question2_answer" required><br><br>

    <label for="qn3">Question 3: <?php echo $array_question[$question_num_array[2]] ?></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="question3_answer" name="question3_answer" required><br><br>

    <!--input type="hidden" name="correct" id="correct" value="<?php $correct ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="incorrect" id="incorrect" value="<?php $incorrect ?>" /-->
    
    <input type="submit" name="submitAnswers" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When you hit the submit button, the answers are posted to testresult.php.

In this file, first checking the answers, then showing the result.

The page doesn't contain questions, so you need to include the php file too.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["submitAnswers"])){
            include 'question.php'; #include the question array.

            $correct = 0;
            $incorrect = 0;
            $qn1_ans = $_POST['question1_answer'];
            $qn2_ans = $_POST['question2_answer'];
            $qn3_ans = $_POST['question3_answer'];

            if ($qn1_ans == $array_answer[$question_num_array[0]]){ $correct ++; }
            else { $incorrect ++; }

            if ($qn2_ans == $array_answer[$question_num_array[1]]){ $correct ++; }
            else { $incorrect ++; }

            if ($qn3_ans == $array_answer[$question_num_array[2]]){ $correct ++; }
            else { $incorrect ++; }

            echo $correct."test ".$incorrect;
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah yes, you are randomly including a file which doesn't exist!

Answer (score 0):

The Form action you've set to your **testresult.php**. So surely the form will carry all of its data to that page. But you are trying to get the data on the same page as `if(isset($_POST["submitAnswers"]))` where is the form; what actually should exist in that **testresult.php** page. So should be like this:

**index.php or something.php**

```
<form action="testresult.php" method="POST">
    <label for="qn1">Question 1: <?php echo $array_question[$question_num_array[0]] ?></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="question1_answer" name="question1_answer" required><br><br>
    
    <label for="qn2">Question 2: <?php echo $array_question[$question_num_array[1]] ?></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="question2_answer" name="question2_answer" required><br><br>

    <label for="qn3">Question 3: <?php echo $array_question[$question_num_array[2]] ?></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="question3_answer" name="question3_answer" required><br><br>

    <input type="hidden" name="correct" id="correct" value="<?php $correct ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="incorrect" id="incorrect" value="<?php $incorrect ?>" />
    
    <input type="submit" name="submitAnswers" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**testresult.php**

```
<?php



// questions array that is called in the form's page should be 
   called here too to get the questions and comparisons.

    if (isset($_POST['submitAnswers'])) {
    $correct = 0;
    $incorrect = 0;
    $qn1_ans = $_POST['question1_answer'];
    $qn2_ans = $_POST['question2_answer'];
    $qn3_ans = $_POST['question3_answer'];

    if ($qn1_ans == $array_answer[$question_num_array[0]]) {
        $correct++;
    } else {
        $incorrect++;
    }

    if ($qn2_ans == $array_answer[$question_num_array[1]]) {
        $correct++;
    } else {
        $incorrect++;
    }

    if ($qn3_ans == $array_answer[$question_num_array[2]]) {
        $correct++;
    } else {
        $incorrect++;
    }
}
?>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Results</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    $correct = $_POST['correct'];
    $incorrect = $_POST['incorrect'];
    
    echo $correct . 'test ' . $incorrect;
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Where did those variables from from?

In your code you're calling two vars `$array_answer` and `$question_num_array`.

None of these two variables are set! Please fix this issue.